# Is there a shorthand for querying a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, syntactic-sugar

Here's the type of query I want to execute, written in pseudocode:

```
select blob from blobs where blob['color'] == 'red' having maximum(blob['size'])
```

Obviously, I could write that like this in python:

```
redBlobs = [];

for blob in blobs:
    if blob['color'] == 'red':
        redBlobs.append('blob')

largestBlob = None

for redBlob in redBlobs:
    if largestBlob == None or redBlob['size'] > largestBlob['size']:
        largestBlob = redBlob

return largestBlob
```

But I suspect there's a cleaner way of doing it. I'm new to python, so I'm still aproaching it very imperatively.

#### EDIT:

Here's a solution I came up with after looking at some other questions on SO:

```
max([blob for blob in blobs if blob['color'] == 'red'], key = lambda b: b['size'])
```

Presumably, there are better ways.

Comment: The edit'd solution is relatively good, it has only one serious problem (apart from the syntax error cause from the lack of a closing `]`): The list comprehensions causes Python to create a whole new list of all red blob objects before starting to evaluate. Use a generator expression and it runs in O(1) space (assuming `max` uses O(1) space, which is almost certain).

Comment: your solution is nearly perfect except three points: first it's missing a ], second it's build a list that is useless with a generator, third you can use operator.itemgetter which is faster than the lambda thing

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The folowing give the largest blob

**EDIT**: catch exception when there is no red blob

```
import operator
try:
    largestBlob = max((blob for blob in blobs if blob['color'] == 'red'),key=operator.itemgetter('size'))
except ValueError:
    largestBlob = None
```

Comment: +1 Perfect. And for the record, `operator.attrgetter` is the equivalent to `itemgetter` if it's an object attribute instead of a dict entry.

Answer (score 1):

This will do the job:

```
redBlobs = filter(lambda b: b['color'] == 'red', blobs)
largestBlob = max(redBlobs, key=lambda b: b['size'])
```

Answer (score 1):

PiotrLegnica's answer will return the size of the largest blob, not the largest blob itself.  To get the largest blob, use the optional "key" argument to max:

```
largestBlob = max((blob for blob in blobs if blob['color'] == 'red'), key=operator.itemgetter('size'))
```

Comment: Indeed, must be `blob for blob in blobs if ...`. Fix that and use `key=operator.itemgetter('size')` and it's about perfect.

Comment: @delnan: I simplified things slightly: `blob` is not a dictionary, but an object, so you'd access 'size' through `blob.size`. Would `operator.itemgetter('size')` still work?

Comment: @Eric: No, but `operator.attrgetter('size')` would.

Comment: @delnan: Thanks for the fixes.  That'll teach me to test my code next time. :)

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would use sorted using the size as key with a generator expression for filetering, getting the first element of that list:

```
largestBlob = sorted((blob for blob in blobs if blob['color'] == 'red'), key=lambda x: -x['size'])[0]
```